# VBA to add hyperlink to bookmark in MS-Word template

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, bookmarks

I need to add a hyperlink to a bookmark in an MS-Word template.  The hyperlink (which changes depending on user input) points to an entry in a database on the web.  I have no trouble building the hyperlink as a string variable, but I can't figure out how to put it in the bookmark so the user winds up with a Word document containing a link that can be clicked to go to the database entry.  My code (below) just deletes the bookmark.  What am I missing?

```
Dim databaseURL As String
' get databaseURL from an existing variable--this part works OK
databaseURL = ActiveDocument.Variables("databaseLink") 

' put the hyperlink in a bookmark named "linkToDatabase"
Dim BMRange As Range
Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("linkToDatabase").Range
BMRange.Text = "Database link"

ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=BMRange, _
                Address:=databaseURL, _
                SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=BMRange.Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to simplify things is to have a bookmarked 'default' hyperlink field at the bookmarked range, then simply change the hyperlink field's code. For example:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("linkToDatabase").Range.Fields(1).Code.Text = "HYPERLINK " & databaseURL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.  My "linkToDatabase" bookmark does have a default hyperlink ({HYPERLINK "https://www.google.com/"}) but my bookmark is still deleted when I replace my code with yours.  I'd appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: Investigating further, I can see that your code works: the correct hyperlink is inserted in the document at the correct bookmarked location.  Something else in my VBA code is apparently deleting the hyperlink after it is inserted, so I need to figure that out.

Comment: Sure enough, I found an error in my code; I was deleting the bookmark after inserting it!  I have nevertheless marked this answer as the solution because it's a simpler, better approach than the one in my OP.  Thanks again.